# Rails 4.2 save value in a session before going to new veiw

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Let’s say I have an index page listed the customer orders and have a button to create a new order as in the image 1.

When I clicked “create new order button” I want Rails to show a message that requests to choose the order type from a list of items before going to the new view (from). When the user chooses the item from the drop down list, he/she can click a button to start filling the new order data, as in image 2.

But before doing that, the value of the selected item has to be saved in a session, so when the “new view/form” opened the system will restore the value from the session and put it in the form. (image 3)

My example more complicated and I really need that message box for different situations.

The problem: I did a lot of tries, but it seems that rails doesn’t save the selected item before going to the new view only!!. surprisingly, when I play with the code, so when the user choose the item from the drop down list and click the button to go to another view in the order controller, it will save the selected item value in the session with no issues.

Your kind help, please

The Image [description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr39q.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In order to save value in session you can use `session[:your_session_variable_name] = params[:item]`

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, in the controller:

```
def new
    session[:type_id]  =  params[:type][:id]
    @order= Order.new
end
```

in the view, using bootstrap Modal

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Choose Order Type </h4>
  </div>
    <%= form_tag(new_order_path , method: :get) do %>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= collection_select(:type, :id, @types_list, :id, :name , class: "form-control") %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <%= button_to "choose", {action: "new"}, {form_class: 'form', class: 'btn btn-md btn-primary'} %>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the value as a variable in the URL? something like the following:

```
http://something.com/object/new?variable_name=value
```

Then in your controller you could do the following

```
value = params[:variable_name]
```

I'm not sure though how you are handling routing to the form page when a user chooses from the modal. I'll show you how in both Ruby and Javascript:

In Rails (Ruby)

```
new_object_path({ 'variable_name' => 'value' })
# would result in something like /objects/new?variable_name=value
```

In Javascript, you could just concatenate in before redirecting to said url

Hope this helps!

Comment: when I open the new View, the URL looks similar to : new?utf8=✓&field%5Bid%5D=16&authenticity_token=05czCv7qmqcCy4QFL6ePxQuldJVXK8ec5HrZ2q9NxVUYBMgCowcTG6mWcmGkcAVJvzXoodBWZuOPbDvdcJg8wg%3D%3D...... Your suggestion is good but how to hide the variable_name's value, so the user cannot play with it

Comment: Let me sure that I understand, you would like to make the url something like this:
`/new?variable_name`

Comment: Let me sure that I understand, you would like to make the url something like this:  
`/new?variable_name`  
Is this correct? If that is the case, it would probably best to store the data in a session variable. Something like:  
`session[:variable_name] = value`